# Django CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing despite being in Response Headers

Tags: django, http, cors

I have a webpage with a Django Backend API and an angular frontend SPA. I have `django-cors-headers==3.5.0`  installed and set up (configurations at the end). When trying to load an .mp3 file from my angular frontend SPA from localhost:4200, and **only** when loading the mp3 file, I receive the following error message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at
> https://www.aldrune.com/media/session_audio/2020-12-01_-_Session_28.mp3.
> (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Please note that at the same time I am able to take a look at the HTTP Request and I can see that contrary to the given error message, the response DOES have the header:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

[image]

What gives? How can I have the header in my response and yet my browser claims it's not there? And why does this only happen with the .mp3 file, while all my media and static-file images, that stem from the exact same application- and http-server are unaffected?

I am aware a lot of similar questions about Djanog and CORS have been asked before, but I couldn't find any that asked while seeing very clearly that the header that supposedly isn't there is very visible in the request.

Below the setup on my server:

```
#settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS : list = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]
...
MIDDLEWARE : list = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    ...
    'csp.middleware.CSPMiddleware',
]
...
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = default_headers + (
    "content-disposition",
)
```

Edit: As requested I went and checked my headers with postman. As he expected, the headers of the response directly to the url of the .mp3 file (https://www.aldrune.com/media/session_audio/2020-12-01_-_Session_28.mp3.) did **not** contain the said header.

[image]

Comment: In fact the response from `https://www.aldrune.com/media/session_audio/2020-12-01_-_Session_28.mp3` has no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, as far as I can see. You can confirm by trying `curl -i "https://www.aldrune.com/media/session_audio/2020-12-01_-_Session_28.mp3"` or with Postman or whatever. The image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/389YH.png doesn’t show a response from `https://www.aldrune.com/media/session_audio/2020-12-01_-_Session_28.mp3` — instead it shows a response from a different URL at `https://www.aldrune.com/wiki1/api/sessionaudio/1/28/`

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thanks for the note, somehow my head had it mixed up that making the API call for the data of the page to play the audio file was the same as loading the audio file, despite the two having 2 different URLs. I checked with postman (see edit above) and yeah, the header is not in there. So this means the serving of the mp3 file likely does not run over my application server, but my http server, an apache2 (? I'm guessing here that that is the case). At which point... do I need to set this somehow up for apache now?

Comment: Wait, that is super confusing. How can my **application server** (django) dictate that there shall be CORS and have those settings transfer to my HTTP server, but somehow the settings from that very same application server to set that CORS header don't transfer over to the HTTP server when it comes to resources that are likely directly served by said HTTP server?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment, but it sounds like you're implying that the requirement for CORS comes from your Django settings. That's not the case; the requirement comes from the browser's use of the Same Origin Policy. So, yes, if it's the case that your media file is being served from a different server then it will also need the appropriate CORS settings. See the documentation for that server software, whatever it is.

Comment: Misunderstanding on my part, I had assumed that the Same-Origin-Policy was "turned on" by my Django Application having the setting in the first place. Well, figured out how to add a CORS Header to my media files in apache, so that worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sideshowbarker and @Kevin Christopher Henry brought me down the correct path on this one. The request that failed was not the one I showed a screenshot for, that was a request to my API for data of the webpage which runs on Django for which I do have a CORS header. The request that failed however was the request explicitly for the .mp3 files. And that one was routed from my HTTP Server directly to my media file, as opposed to running through Django where it would've received a CORS header.

Also contrary to my previous understanding the browser is the one stating by default via its Same-Origin-Policy that I, running my frontend dev-server on localhost, do not get access to content on my server aldrune.com unless the server says that this origin "localhost" is ok.

So given that (based on how you typically deploy with Django) your files are served via the HTTP Server and not via Django, you need to configure your HTTP Server to give back a CORS header that allows your localhost to access the file, in my case that was Apache.

As such I added a rule to my apache config specifically for my media files to allow the localhost origin - no need to allow more than necessary. [A short resource about this can be found here.](https://tecadmin.net/enable-cors-apache/)

```
        <Directory /path/to/my/media/directory>
                ... //Other settings for this directory not shown

                SetEnvIf Origin "(http)?(s)?(://)?(www\.)?(localhost:4200|aldrune.com.*)" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
                Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
                Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
        </Directory>
```